# ElasticSearch 7.13.4. How do I get a document by its number

Tags: elasticsearch

I am testing ElasticSearch with my own .Net crawler. It's working well. However I notice some searches produce a response error thus

```
query - all shards failed - Type: illegal_argument_exception Reason: "The length [1140599] of field [contents] in doc[19800]/index[myindex] exceeds the [index.highlight.max_analyzed_offset] limit [1000000].
```

I am able to increase the max_analyzed_offset and sort the issue, but what I really want to do is view the document in its entirety.  The error gives me the document by its ordinal index - doc[19800]/index[myindex].  From what I can tell, 19800 refers to the documents number in the index, it's not the document Id so what I need to access is document # 19800 in my index.  Is there a way to view this document (doc[19800]/index[myindex]) using the ElasticSearch 7.13.4 API?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the error message you shared was produced by this line of code, within Elasticsearch 7.13:

```
"The length [" + fieldValueLength + "] of field [" + field +"] in doc[" + docId + "]/index[" + index +"] exceeds the ["
                    + IndexSettings.MAX_ANALYZED_OFFSET_SETTING.getKey() + "] limit [" + maxAnalyzedOffset + "].
...
```

Ref: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/7.13/server/src/main/java/org/apache/lucene/search/uhighlight/CustomUnifiedHighlighter.java#L123

Therefore the number in the error message is actually the document id (docId).

The simplest way to get the whole document using the id is with the GET API.
See [Elasticsearch Guide [7], GET API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/docs-get.html)

Comment: Many thanks for the response. I did try your suggestion before posting but it did not work.  When I try the api to get a document with id 19800, it returns not found.  When I look at my documents in Kibana, the _id parameter seems to be the original url of the crawled web page.